# Default parameters if textBox is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this to filter the table.

```
using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                myDatabaseConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee WHERE EmpID >= @from  AND EmpID <= @to", myDatabaseConnection))
                {
                    mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", textBox1.Text);
                    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", textBox2.Text);
                    {
                        ds = new DataSet();
                        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
                        adapter.Fill(ds, "Employee");
                    }
                }
            }
```

For example I have `4001` in textBox1 and `4017` in texBox2. I gives me the result of `4001`,`4002`,`4003` . . . `4017`

The problem is for example I `4001` in textBox1 and none in textBox2 it gives no result. How I will do it to have a result from `4001` until to the last value of the table? And if the textBox1 is empty and textBox2 is `4017` , the result will be 1,2,3 up to 4017 assuming that 1 have the least value?

Comment: What do you mean by this `the last value of the table`? What table?

Comment: Employee Table. I mean the highest value of EmpID. My EmpID Column is identity that's why I said the last value. Sorry.

Comment: If your `EmpID` has value of integral number format, you may want to check out the solution given below, it should work, however notice about the `textBox1.text`, it should be `textBox1.Text`. Your want means that if the `textBox2` is empty, the query should take all the record from the lowest `EmpID` as specified in `textBox1`, `taking all` doesn't require us to know the maximum of `EmpID`, that's why you can pass in a large number instead (such as `99999`). The same logic is applied to the case when `textBox1` is empty, we just pass in as a small number as possible (such as `0`).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would be to default the values for @from and @to to minimum and maximum values for empty textbox

eg. if the EmpId is Integer

```
int minId = 0;
int maxId = 99999;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.text))
minId = int.Parse(textBox1.text);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.text))
maxId = int.Parse(textBox2.text);

mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", minId);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", maxId);
```

doing so, you always will have a value to compare against.

Comment: you may be some kind of `scripter`? don't care much about case-sensitivity? Don't care much about data type? BTW the default value of `TextBox.Text` is `string.Empty` not `null`.

Comment: You are spot on. It would be wise to make a check next time before posting - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, this should work:

```
using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand {Connection = myDatabaseConnection})
{
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = "Select * from Employee WHERE " + 
    textBox2.Text.Trim() == "" ? "EmpID >= @from" : "EmpID >= @from  AND EmpID <= @to";
    mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", textBox1.Text.Trim() != "" ? textBox1.Text : int.Parse(textBox2.Text.Trim()) - 3);
    if(textBox2.Text.Trim() != "")
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", textBox2.Text);

    ds = new DataSet();
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
    adapter.Fill(ds, "Employee");                    
}
```